# $setValidity | TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

so here is my problem, i send an ajax request and on the back if want to show a message, only i have this error : TypeError: Cannot read property '$setValidity' of undefined

here is my js code :

```
$http.post('controleur/conn/creationCompte.php', {
            "login" : $scope.login,
            "mdp"   : $scope.mdp1,
            "mail"  : $scope.mail
        })

        .success(function(data){
            alert(data);
            if(data.indexOf("err:0") != -1) {$scope.creationForm.retour.$setValidity("ret_err", false);};
            if(data.indexOf("pseudo:0") != -1) {$scope.creationForm.retour.$setValidity("ret_err_pseudo", false);};
            if(data.indexOf("email:0") != -1) {$scope.creationForm.retour.$setValidity("ret_err_email", false);};
            if(data.indexOf("ret:1") != -1) {$scope.creationForm.retour.$setValidity("ret_insc_ok", false);};
        })
        .error(function(){
            alert("Un problème est survenu, veuillez renouveller l'opération ultérieurement ou contacter un administrateur du site.");
        });
```

and here is my html :

```
<form name="creationForm" role="form" ng-submit="createAccount()">
<div ng-model="retour"></div>
<ng-messages ng-if="creationForm.retour.$dirty" for="creationForm.retour.$error" ng-messages-include="erreur/error-messages.html" class="my-messages"></ng-messages>
</form>
```

ty for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found the problem. We must use an input with ng-messages like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="retour" ng-model="retour">
<ng-messages for="creationForm.retour.$error" ng-messages-include="erreur/error-messages.html" class="my-messages"></ng-messages>
```

And it works fine :)

Comment: hi sir what if if i have model name like this model="employee.profile.username" how can i bind that to my form??